# How to use this as a variable instead of a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am creating a API using node js and mongo db. I want to implement a search.
Here the following is my code

```
router.post('/searchstudents', async(req, res) => {


    const qualifications = await Qualification.find({
        qualification: /req.body.searchkey/
    });

    res.send(qualifications);

});
```

In here this `req.body.searchkey` is identified as a string and does not give me the output.
How to use it as a variable so I can send random values ?

I want to use `/someString/` as the like operator in Sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $regex if you want to search.

```
router.post('/searchstudents', async(req, res) => {
    const qualifications = await Qualification.find({
        qualification: { $regex: new RegExp(req.body.searchkey) }
    }).lean();
    return res.status(200).json(qualifications);
});
```

Warning: It's not safe to use regex like that since it can be exploited. Please read this to know more about it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727773/8892700